# Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

Tags: bootstrap-4, poppler

Como que resolve o problema do Popper no bootstrap 4.0

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
```

Instalei o Popper via npm ai deu esse erro,mas colocando-o via CDN, dá okay.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor como você referenciou o popper no seu projeto, pois você apenas disse que instalou ele.

Comment: você está utilizado alguma ferramenta para build da aplicação? Ex: gulp, grunt ou webpack?